# What's the rationale of Swift's size methods taking `Int`s?

Tags: swift

I've noticed a lot of swift built ins take or return `Int`s and not `UInt`s:

Here are some examples from `Array`:

```
mutating func reserveCapacity(minimumCapacity: Int)

var capacity: Int { get }

init(count: Int, repeatedValue: T)

mutating func removeAtIndex(index: Int) -> T
```

Given that the language is completely new, and assuming that this design choice was not arbitrary - I'm wondering: **Why do swift built ins take `Int`s and not `UInt`s?**

Some notes: Asking because I'm working on a few collections myself and I'm wondering what types I should use for things like `reserveCapacity` etc. What I'd naturally expect is for `reserveCapacity` to take a `UInt` instead.

Answer (score 10):

`UInt` is a common cause of bugs. It is very easy to accidentally generate a -1 and wind up with infinite loops or similar problems. (Many C and C++ programmers have learned the hard way that you really should just use `int` unless there's a need for `unsigned`.) Because of how Swift manages type conversion, this is even more important. If you've ever worked with `NSUInteger` with "signed-to-unsigned" warnings turned on (which are an error in Swift, not an optional warning like in C), you know what a pain that is.

The Swift Programming Guide explains their specific rationale in the section on `UInt`:

> NOTE
>
> Use UInt only when you specifically need an unsigned integer type with the same size as the platform’s native word size. If this is not the case, Int is preferred, even when the values to be stored are known to be non-negative. A consistent use of Int for integer values aids code interoperability, avoids the need to convert between different number types, and matches integer type inference, as described in Type Safety and Type Inference.

Comment: In Swift the issue you described is a non-issue though. You _can't_ pass an int with a negative value as a UInt and have it type-convert. (Like you said, it's an Error in Swift).

Comment: Exactly. So you often wind up having to do `UInt(x) + y` to keep it in the `UInt` space. If you create a constant, for instance, it'll type-inferance to an `Int`, so you have to cast it. If you work with anything that returns an `Int` (and lots of things do), you'll have to cast it. The casting becomes very excessive, and you stop paying attention to whether the cast is actually safe; you can't always just cast an int to an unsigned or vice versa. When you factor in the very common unsigned bug of "while x <= y - 1" where y can be 0, it's just much cleaner to just stay in the Int space.

Comment: This is a lesson hard-learned from C, ObjC, and C++ which have similar problems. Swift is trying to dodge that common bug. See the Google C++ style guide for one of many places recommending the same behavior in Swift's predecessors: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Integer_Types "You should not use the unsigned integer types such as uint32_t, unless there is a valid reason such as representing a bit pattern... In particular, do not use unsigned types to say a number will never be negative. Instead, use assertions for this."

Comment: The link to Google's style guide is outdated. Here is the new one: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Integer_Types

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *possible* explanation (I am no expert on this subject): Suppose you have this code

```
let x = 3
test(x)

func test(t: Int) {
}
```

This will compile without a problem, since the type of 'x' is inferred to be Int.

However, if you change the function to

```
func test(t: UInt) {
}
```

The compiler will give you a build error (`'Int' is not convertible to 'UInt'`)

So my guess is that it is just for convenience, because Swift's type safety would otherwise require you to convert them manually each time.

Comment: For what it's worth [that was my guess too](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/19026152#19026152) but it's a rather wild guess and doing `let x:UInt = 3` would fix it or `test(UInt(x))`. Both seem a lot more "Swiftic"

Comment: Well, I disagree ;-) I think it looks a lot cleaner without the type annotation/conversion.

Comment: In particular, the `UInt(x)` might not even be possible. It could fail. You need to think about that every time you use it. And if you use `x:UInt`, then the same problem comes up if you need to pass it to something taking `Int`. Imagine the not-uncommon case where `x` is `scale` and might be applied to both positives or negatives, including things that should only be positive. You get into a flip-flop, switching your `scale` constant between `Int` and `UInt`, trying to get the one that is more often what you want (or you create *two* constants, which is even uglier).

Comment: (BTW, that example comes from my actual Swift code. I started out trying to use `UInt` to mean "can't be negative" and quickly learned why that is not a good idea, and *then* discovered that Apple also mentioned not to do it.)